# how to remove all objects that belong to the same object in Realm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have model class. It's name is LifelineModel. This class has another model class LifelineProductModel. I'm removing LifelineModel object if I have more than two objects of this class. But LifelineProductModel object remains. How can I remove depending objects in Realm?

```
    static func saveActieLifelineModel(model: LifelineModel) {
    do {
        try realm.write({
            realm.add(model, update: true)
        })
        print("saveActieLifelineModel success")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("saveActieLifelineModel error", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let modelArray = realm.objects(LifelineModel).toArray()
    if modelArray.count > 1 {
        do {
            try realm.write({
                guard let inActiveModel = modelArray.first else { return }
                realm.delete(inActiveModel)
            })
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, Realm doesn't automatically delete objects that are linked from the object intended for deletion (Although [it's on our roadmap](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1186)!)

At the moment, it will be necessary to manually delete the linked `LifelineProductModel` objects yourself before deleting the parent `LifelineModel`.

Comment: do this functionality still not exist?

Comment: Have a look at the issue I linked. There was some progress posted a few days ago. :)

Answer (score -1):

From 0.87.0 there is an option:

```
let aVar = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

aVar.deleteAllObjects()
```

Comment: No, I do not need to delete the objects, as there are some needs. me only those objects which are needed to remove the first object.